# Jersey seemingly adding port onto url in client request

Tags: java, ssl, client, jersey

I'm using some basic Java code to send a RESTful request through Jersey and for some reason Jersey is appending the :443 port to the end of all of my URLs which causes CAS to fail (proxy tickets are generated elsewhere for a specific URL; adding in port breaks this).

Is there a way to tell Jersey to NOT send the 443 port as part of the URL?

Edit: fyi I deleted my previous ticket before realizing that the issue is truly inside of Jersey.

Edit2: Added code below; I had to strip out a few items but this is essentially what I'm using. It's in a generic method to work with a specific API we're working with; I added the doNotSend mode stuff in to test the url; the url gets returned from that without :443 but when it executes through Jersey it has :443 added which throws CAS authentication off.

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
}};
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
    ;
}

Client client = Client.create();

String url = Configuration.getOption(CONFIG_REST_URL) + actionPath;
if (dontSendMode) {
    GGResponse r = new GGResponse();
    r.setUrl(url);
    return r;
}
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(proxy_ticket)) {
    if (url.contains("?")) {
        url += "&";
    } else {
        url += "?";
    }
    url += String.format("ticket=%s", proxy_ticket);
}
WebResource.Builder resourceBuilder = client
        .resource(url)
        .accept("application/json");

ClientResponse response = null;
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
    response = resourceBuilder.get(ClientResponse.class);
}
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
    response = resourceBuilder.post(ClientResponse.class, json);
}
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE")) {
    response = resourceBuilder.delete(ClientResponse.class);
}
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")) {
    response = resourceBuilder.put(ClientResponse.class, json);
}

String output = null;
String etagResponse = null;
String error = null;

if (response != null && response.getStatus() == 200) {
    output = response.getEntity(String.class);
} else {
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

Comment: Because I'm not well versed in jersey client, can you show the code that makes the request?

Comment: Added. I should have done that in the first place.

Comment: I resolved this myself by simply updating my configuration settings in other places to always use :443 on my SSL URLs but...well, that doesn't seem like the best way to go. I'll add it as an answer if no one has any additional ideas.